# DataBinding in android

Tags: android, data-binding

i am using data binding in one android project in which we set some data in layout ,the data comes from sever everything works fine ,my problem is that when we set some icon in image view according the data which comes from server,first time its works but after scrolling it crashes.how i resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

```
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <data>
    <variable
        name="lead"
        type="com.enquirydetails.UnassignedLeadObject" />
    <import type="android.view.View" />

</data>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:app=
   "http://schemas.android.com  /apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
    android:background="@color/bg_color_card"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/four_dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/five_dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/vSideLine"
                android:layout_width="3dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/five_dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llEnqName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="8"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvEnqName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_heading_color"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_eighteen"
                            android:text="@{lead.CustomerName}"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivHotImg"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:contentDescription=
                            "@string/img_description"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/six_dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/hot"
                            android:visibility=
                          "@{lead.isWarm  ?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"

                            />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivBookedImg"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:contentDescription=
                            "@string/img_description"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/four_dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/book"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="right|center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_call_phone"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/eight_dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/call_new" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llEnqDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/llEnqName"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/eight_dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvEnqDetails"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvEnqTime"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:text="@{lead.InterestedIn}"
                        android:textColor="@color/filter_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_twelve" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvEnqTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@{lead.LatestInquiryDate}"
                        android:textColor="@color/followuo_date_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_twelve" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvBuySell"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/filter_text_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_twelve" />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvEnqSrc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/llEnqDetails"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/enq_list_det"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_twelve" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Please provide your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,there is some bug in imageView inflate please provide your object model from where you set the values.